# Assigning permission set to user in apex

Tags: knowledge, permission-sets, lightning-knowledge

Is it possible?  Are there any limitations to consider?  I have a use case where if a certain relationship is maybe, we would assign a permission set that grants access to a knowledge base data category.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Turns out it's very easy:

```
PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment
(PermissionSetId = myPermissionSetId, AssigneeId = myAssigneeId);
insert psa;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
List<PermissionSetAssignment> permissionSetList = new List<PermissionSetAssignment>();
for (User u : [SELECT ID,UserRole.Name,Profile.Name,IsActive FROM User WHERE  UserRole.Name LIKE '%manager%' AND Profile.Name != 'Operations Manager' AND IsActive = true]){ // Add fields as per your requirement...
    PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment (PermissionSetId = '0PSq00000009qDNGAY', AssigneeId = u.Id);
    permissionSetList.add(psa);
}
try{
    upsert permissionSetList;
}catch(exception e){
    system.debug('exception caught' + e);
}
```

Apex code to Assign Permission Set to Users 
Created this . Change the query as per requirement and use it , works always

Comment: Can you add some explanation of *why* this code answers the question?