# Add Community members via Apex?

Tags: apex, community, security

Is it possible to add/change/delete Community members using Apex?  I know how to do this via the UI (see picture below), but I'm looking to automate some things on the demo side of the business for our sales reps.

[image]

Comment: Good question! AFAIK, we might not be able to get this functionality via Apex. I would like to see if anyone have ever solved this using Apex. +1

Comment: I *think* you can do it using the Metadata API. Is that an option?

Comment: I haven't invoked the Metadata API via Apex before.  Where would I go to find examples of that?

Comment: I didn't mean via Apex as such (although that is possible but deeply messy, [`apex-mdapi`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)) - how are you creating these demo orgs? Can you run an MDAPI deployment as part of the process?

Comment: Our demo orgs are Trialforced.  I'm not sure if MDAPI can be called as part of the process.

Comment: Simplest would be to use dataloader: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000338383&type=1&mode=1, otherwise writing metadata API code mentioned by David is a best available option; if this is really needed to be updated frequently.

Comment: @Raul the update is only needs to be done once, when an org is first created.

Comment: How do you generate your org, is it scratch orgs with SFDX? If yes, you could automate with some scripting with pupeteer npm package as mentioned by [Wade wedgner on twitter](https://twitter.com/wadewegner/status/1082481589827694592?lang=en).

Comment: @Raul the orgs in question are created from orgs setup for the Trialforce process.

Answer (score 1):

Although Salesforce says 'create' allowed on Network Member: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_networkmember.htm, but seems that not allowed using apex code. No worries, we can make a post REST call for the same:

First add your salesforce base url as remote site setting then add this code as part of your implementation:

```
        String endpoint = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/NetworkMemberGroup';
        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();  
        httpRequest.setEndpoint(endpoint);  
        httpRequest.setMethod('POST'); 
        httpRequest.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID()); 
        httpRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'); 

        //Change network id and profile/permission set Id
httpRequest.setBody('{"NetworkId":"0DB900000008Qga","ParentId":"00e90000001uNre"}');
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);
```

A very detailed explanation is given here: https://sfdcian.com/manage-community-member-programmatically/

Comment: How would I use that technique to add community members?

Comment: Add community profile id as ParentId field...

Answer (score 0):

I feel you can simplify things using the permission set. You can give community access using [permission sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_members.htm&type=5).

And the best thing is we can assign permission sets using apex. Thus simplifying your work would be just assigning PS to the select user in apex.

```
 PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment
    (PermissionSetId = communityAccessPS, AssigneeId = userId);
    insert psa;
```

src: [Assigning permission set to user in apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60668/assigning-permission-set-to-user-in-apex)

Comment: I don't think this technique can be used to change the sharing settings for external users to Public Read/Write.

Comment: @MichaelSobczak but main question was how to add or remove community member via apex? And the above solution works?

Comment: My mistake!  I have two issues going on, both involve community settings.